# What to do if Array.from() is not supported for IE?

Tags: javascript

I am using `Array.from()` function which is supported in all browsers, except IE:

```
function range(start, end) {
    return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start);
}
```

Instead of `Array.from()` what function can I use to make my code compatible with IE?

Comment: have you tried a loop?

Answer (score 4):

Use a **Polyfill**.

```
if (!Array.from) {
    Array.from = (function () {
        // The code gose here...
    })();
}
```

**As described in Mozilla please refer below link,**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill

Comment: Syntax error is coming near by Array.from line on IE
function range(start, end) {
        return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start);
    }

I am using below Polyfill in my js file but still syntax error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop

```js
function range(start, end) {
    var array = [];
    for(i = start; i<=end; i++) {
      array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}
console.log(range(3, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Array.from it is the arrow function, try

```
function range(start, end) {
  return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), function (_, i) { return i + start; });
}
```

Comment: In below code near by item => is showing syntax error in Internet explorer 


getPageList2(totalPages2, currentPage2, paginationSize2).forEach( item => { jQuery("<li>").addClass("page-item_asset") .addClass(item ? "current-page_asset" : "disabled") .toggleClass("active", item === currentPage2).append( jQuery("<a>").addClass("page-link_asset").attr({ href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text(item || "...") ).insertBefore("#next-page_asset"); });